# WordPress nl2br is not converting newline to html line break when saving metabox value

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I tried possible solutions to save `\n` as `<br />` from my custom post type `<textarea>` metabox but it is not working.

I am using a custom made theme and there is no additional plugin installed.

```
function abhijaan_itinerary_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'trek_itinerary', 'trek_itinerary_nonce' );
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_trek_itinerary', true );
    $content = preg_replace( '#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $content );
    ?>
    <textarea class="trek_inputs required" name="txtItinerary" id="txtItinerary" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Itinerary" required><?php echo $content ?></textarea>
    <?php
}


function save_custom_metaboxes( $post_id ) {
   ...
   $itinerary = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['txtItinerary'] );
   $itinerary = nl2br( $itinerary ); // NOT WORKING!
   update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_trek_itinerary', $itinerary );
   ...
}

add_action( 'save_post',  'save_custom_metaboxes' );
```

Before usinng `<textarea>`, I tried `WYSIWYG` editor as well. That too had the same issue.

```
function abhijaan_itinerary_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'trek_itinerary', 'trek_itinerary_nonce' );
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_trek_itinerary', true );

    wp_editor(
            $content,
            'txtItinerary',
            array( 'media_buttons' => false )
    );
}
```

I am expecting the data to be saved with `<br />` in `wp_postmeta` table, but it is not happening. I have multiple metaboxes which are using `<textarea>`. What is going wrong? :(

**UPDATE 1**

In fact default post editor (content area) is not saving paragraphs! But if I use other HTML formatting like bullets, they are saved. It is only the `<p>` tag which is not saving at all from anywhere!

**UPDATE 2**
I am using WordPress 5.2.2. `Classic Editor` plugin is not installed. However, in my CPT, the default editor is the old one however block editor is coming up when I am writing a normal `Post` (not CPT). I am fine with the old editor in my CPT, but don't know why the paragraphs are always ignored!

**UPDATE 3 (Screenshots)**

Backend:
[image]

Frontend:
[image]

**UPDATE 4**
`wpautop( the_content() )` has resolved the content paragraph issue on frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [reference/description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/#description) of `sanitize_text_field()`:

> - Checks for invalid UTF-8,
> - Converts single < characters to entities
> - Strips all tags
> - **Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace**
> - Strips octets

So a simple fix is, use [`sanitize_textarea_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/):

> The function is like
>   [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/),
>   but **preserves new lines (\n) and other whitespace**, which are
>   legitimate input in textarea elements.

```php
// In save_custom_metaboxes()
$itinerary = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['txtItinerary'] ); // use this one
//$itinerary = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['txtItinerary'] );   // and not this
```

### Additional Notes

Also, you should use `esc_textarea()` (although the output may not contain HTML tags):

```php
<textarea class="trek_inputs required" name="txtItinerary"...><?php echo // wrapped for clarity
  esc_textarea( $content ); ?></textarea>
```

And you'd also want to remove line break after each `<br />`:

```php
$itinerary = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['txtItinerary'] );
$itinerary = nl2br( $itinerary );
// Removes line break after each <br />, if any.
$itinerary = preg_replace( "#<br />(\r\n|\n|\r)#", '<br />', $itinerary );
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great for metaboxes. But why the paragraphs of the main content of my post are not rendering? It is not a meta! Please suggest. I have updated my original question with screenshots.

Comment: Well, you got it sorted already - using `wpautop()`. And actually, you could also use that function with the meta boxes - `wpautop( $itinerary )` instead of `nl2br( $itinerary )`. That way, you wouldn't need the `$content = preg_replace( '#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $content );` in `abhijaan_itinerary_metabox()`.